# Atlassian Soucetree 2.3.1.0: Difference between 'remove' and 'discard'

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using Atlassian Soucetree 2.3.1.0 for Windows. When I right click a file under 'Unstaged files' there's an option to Remove and also an option to Discard. What's the difference? What I want is the equivelent of TFS's "undo pending changes". I accidentally made a change to a file and I want to undo it without affecting the repo in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same SourceTree 2.3.1.0, and I see:

- remove (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>) is a `git rm -- afile`
- Discard is a `git checkout -- afile`, which will reset the content to what is in the index: so it will undo pending changes not yet staged.

[image: remove vs. Discard]